# What do the Chimpy Cam options do?

Tags: donkey-kong-64

In the options for Donkey Kong 64 I can set Chimpy Cam to either Free or Follow. What's the difference between Free and Follow?

[image: Chimpy Cam set to Free]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Free** means that you can handle the camera manually.
**Follow** means that the camera will tend to go behind the character.

Comment: What do the camera control buttons do when Follow is selected?

Comment: If I have to guess, you can probably still move the camera and it will then return behind the player. You may test this by yourself if you own the game.